# Parse error parse error in php error

Tags: php

Parse error: parse error in /Users/MyName/Desktop/folder/test.php

Oh btw i'm using a mac

Why does this error keep coming up? I've put it through a phpchecker but it's showing no errors?

```
<?php
$handle = popen('ls -l', "r");
while ($line = fgets($handle)) {
 echo $line;
 $fields = preg_split("/\s+/", $line); 
 $i = 0 ;
 while ($i < count($fields)) {
 echo " field $i is ", $fields[$i], "\n";
 $i++ ;
 }
}
?>
```

Comment: Not enough error info error.

Comment: It looks ok to me, putting that in a file and running it passes the lint checker (php -l) and running it gives useful output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>here</strike>

```
echo " field $i is ", $fields[$i], "\n";
```

use dots instead of commas to concatenate strings:

```
echo " field $i is ". $fields[$i]. "\n";
```

see: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php

**Edit:** I need to correct myself even though OP's problem is obviously solved.
While string concatenation operator is `.` , echo accepts multiple parameters that are concatenated. And as we know parameters are separated by `,`.

Comment: @dsas You are right, I didn't know that. I updated my answer.